# for loop repeating in for each loop

Tags: php

I am having `for` loop in `foreach` loop

```
static $count=0;
for($i=$count;$i<$semesters_count;$i++)
{
    echo $array_wam[$i];
    $count++;
}
```

here `$array_wam` is array of some marks.  I am printing multiple student marks 
 I getting first student marks

```
first student
  50.6 

second student 
 50.6  60.9
```

I want to show output like

```
  first student
  50.6 

second student 
 60.9
```

Here loop again starts with 0 but I want loop starts with where it ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to put static `$count=0;` before the `foreach` starts.

See an example below:

```
static $count=0;

foreach ($item)
{
    for($i=$count;$i<$semesters_count;$i++)
    {
        echo $array_wam[$i];
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? It will only initialize it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if i am understanding right what you are asking for but have you tried like this?

```
for($i=0;$i<$semesters_count;$i++){
    echo $array_wam[$i];
}
```

Comment: This will start at 0 for each student, instead of the current place in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  for($i = 0; $i < $count_semester; $i++){
    echo $array_wam[$i];
  }
```

Why do you want `static $count` if it can loop trough `for` loop? And it still counters your `$i` variable is equal to the length of your `$count_semester`.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not incrementing `$count` when you reach the end of the `for` loop.

Instead of incrementing `$count` inside the loop, set it to `$i` at the end of the loop:

```
static $count = 0;
for ($i = $count; $i < $semesters_count; $i++) {
    echo $array_wam[$i];
}
$count = $i;
```

Comment: missed a $ in count inside forloop

Comment: hi barmar i tried with this code but its not coming, suppose im having array_wam valus for first student of $i=0 and 1 then next student for loop starts with $i= 2  and so an

Comment: @Nadh Isn't that what you want? Your code was repeating `1` when starting the second student.

Comment: I had a typo, `, $i++` instead of `; $i++`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
static $count = 0;

foreach ($item)
{
    $semester_count_total = $semesters_count + $count;

    for ($i = $count; $i < $semester_count_total; $i++) {
       echo $array_wam[$i];
    }

    $count = $semester_count_total;
}
```